# Is it possible to submit a batch job to the deezer API?

Tags: deezer

I am using the Deezer API for a competition, I'd like to submit a batch job to retrieve information about 452975 tracks, 151471 albums and 67142 artists. The deezer API has a request quota of 50 requests per 5 seconds, which will make this take a very long time (excluding overhead). So my question, is it possible to submit a batch job?

I've looked into doing some smarter things than just retrieve all the songs, albums and artists. Since I assumed that retrieving the album, would also yield the artist, and the featured songs. But the artist/song parts of the JSON do not supply me with all the information I can get if I request information about a particular song, namely: BPM and GAIN are missing when I look at the song information through the album API. I feel like this could and should be improved by the Deezer API team.

But to get back to my main question: is it possible to submit a batch job in any way to the Deezer API, something like:

`http://api.deezer.com/track/3135553&3135554&3132233`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you cannot submit a batch job on our REST API for now, we will consider that possibility.

Comment: I guess it's an answer, not the answer I hoped for since I don't have much time left since I'm competing in the DSG. But thanks anyway!